# How to remove unwanted fields from lists of dictionary in python using for loop

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, fastapi

```
[{
    'field_name': 'mobile',
    'field_value': '8888888822',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'name',
    'field_value': 'putta',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'job',
    'field_value': 'Student',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'place'
    'field_value': 'xyz',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'vilage',
    'field_value': '',
    'type': 'primary'
}]
```

This is my json here i need to get the length of the list, and this is returning **5**.
now i need to leave **job field** and **place field** from the **list length** and also fields which are having empty values example **vilage field** i am able to read field_name or field value using lambda function but not both(lamda accept only one parameter) how to acheive this.  thanks for inputs.  **expected output length= 2**

Comment: iterate over the list of dicts and apply the needed conditons

Comment: "now i need to leave job field from the count" - I have absolutely no idea what this is supposed to mean. It doesn't say "count" anywhere in the example.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever "now i need to leave job field from the list length..."?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to leave out elements where `field_name` is `job` or `field_value` is `''`. This can be achieved in a loop:

```py
input_list = [{
    'field_name': 'mobile',
    'field_value': '8888888822',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'name',
    'field_value': 'putta',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'job',
    'field_value': 'Student',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'place',
    'field_value': '',
    'type': 'primary'
}, {
    'field_name': 'vilage',
    'field_value': '',
    'type': 'primary'
}]

count = 0
for el in input_list:
    if el.get('field_name', 'job') != 'job' and el.get('field_value', None):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Using `get(..)` allows you to leave out elements that don't have `field_name` or `field_value` as key.

You can also achieve this with a comprehension:

```py
len([el for el in input_list if el.get('field_name', 'job') != 'job' and el.get('field_value', None)])
```